# Adding df column finding matching values in another df for both indexed values and a dynamic source column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Simplified dfs:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "ID": [6, 2, 4],
        "to ignore": ["foo", "whatever", "idk"],
        "value": ["A", "B", "A"],
    }
)

df2 = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "ID_number": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
        "A": [0.91, 0.42, 0.85, 0.84, 0.81, 0.88],
        "B": [0.11, 0.22, 0.45, 0.38, 0.01, 0.18],
    }
)

   ID to ignore value
0   6       foo     A
1   2  whatever     B
2   4       idk     A

   A     B  ID_number
0  0.91  0.11          1
1  0.42  0.22          2
2  0.85  0.45          3
3  0.84  0.38          4
4  0.81  0.01          5
5  0.88  0.18          6
```

I want to add a column to `df` which includes combinations of `df['ID']` to `df2['ID_number']` and `df['value']` to the `df2` column matching the value in `df[value]` (either 'A' or 'B').

We can add a column of matching values where the lookup column name in `df2` is given, 'A':

```
df["NewCol"] = df["ID"].map(
    df2.drop_duplicates("ID_number").set_index("ID_number")["A"]
)
```

Which gives:

```
   ID to ignore value  NewCol
0   6       foo     A    0.88
1   2  whatever     B    0.42
2   4       idk     A    0.84
```

But this doesn't give values for B, so the value '0.42' above when looking for 'B' should instead be '0.22'.

```
df["NewCol"] = df["ID"].map(
    df2.drop_duplicates("ID_number").set_index("ID_number")[df["value"]]
)
```

obviously doesn't work. How can do I this?

Comment: can you please share desired output so we can know what you mean? Is it the same set of ids but just that B should have 0.22 instead of 0.42?

Comment: Take his last example and change 0.42 in new_col to 0.22

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set `ID_number` as index in `df2`,then use [`pd.Index.get_indexer`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.get_indexer.html) here.

```
df2 = df2.set_index('ID_number')
r = df2.index.get_indexer(df['ID'])
c = df2.columns.get_indexer(df['value'])
df['new_col'] = df2.values[r, c]
df

   ID to ignore value  new_col
0   6       foo     A     0.88
1   2  whatever     B     0.22
2   4       idk     A     0.84
```

#### Timeits

Benchmarked using the below setup:

Tested on Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS(focal), Cpython3.8.5, Ipython shell(7.18.1), pandas(1.1.4), numpy(1.19.2)

**Setup**

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "ID_number": np.arange(1, 1_000_000 + 1),
        "A": np.random.rand(1_000_000),
        "B": np.random.rand(1_000_000),
    }
)

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "ID": np.random.randint(1, 1_000_000, 50_000),
        "to ignore": ["anything"] * 50_000,
        "value": np.random.choice(["A", "B"], 50_000),
    }
)
```

Resutls:

```
@Vaishali
In [57]: %%timeit
    ...: mapper = df2.set_index('ID_number').to_dict('index')
    ...: df['NewCol'] = df.apply(lambda x: mapper[x['ID']][x['value']], axis =
    ...: 1)
    ...: 
    ...: 
2.09 s ± 68.2 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

@Ch3steR
In [58]: %%timeit
    ...: t = df2.set_index('ID_number')
    ...: r = t.index.get_indexer(df['ID'])
    ...: c = t.columns.get_indexer(df['value'])
    ...: df['new_col'] = df2.values[r, c]
    ...: 
    ...: 
49.7 ms ± 2.69 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

@Mayank
In [59]: %%timeit
    ...: x = df2.set_index('ID_number').stack()
    ...: y = df.set_index(['ID', 'value'])
    ...: y['NewCol'] = y.index.to_series().map(x.to_dict())
    ...: y.reset_index(inplace=True)
    ...: 
    ...: 
3.41 s ± 226 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

@Jezrael
In [60]: %%timeit
    ...: df11 = (df2.melt('ID_number', value_name='NewCol', var_name='value')
    ...:            .drop_duplicates(['ID_number','value'])
    ...:            .rename(columns={'ID_number':'ID'}))
    ...: df.merge(df11, on=['ID','value'], how='left')
    ...: 
    ...: 
693 ms ± 16.1 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Comment: @jezrael I'm creating a larger dataframe currently will update with those results.

Comment: Super, is possible post it how was created?

Comment: @jezrael Yes sure, will post it.

Comment: @jezrael Updated the answer check for timeit results.

Comment: Btw, one improvement, 100 values like `A,B` and also duplicates, this should failed for your solution I guess.

Comment: It's one million. Python allows you to separate numbers with `_` for readability.

Comment: @jezrael If there are dupes in column names my solution would fail. Since you handled that too +1 to you. And about [`underscores in numeric literals`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0515/)

Comment: If there are unique column names `.get_indexer` + NumPy indexing is beast tho :P Avoiding all the overhead of pandas @jezrael

Comment: I've just learned the hard way that if the indexer value doesn't match it appears to use the last available option without raising an error (eg. try `"value": ["A", "B", "asdf"]`). @Ch3steR perhaps you could revise your answer to incorporate a validation or warn about this

Comment: [Documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.get_indexer.html?highlight=get_indexer#pandas.Index.get_indexer) details default `method` being exact matches only but this doesn't appear to be demonstrated. Have I misunderstood?

Comment: [Unmatched values return -1](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/38482) and this must be filtered for. To kill if any unmatched values: `if -1 in np.array([r, c]): exit()`

Comment: @ChrisDixon Sorry couldn't get back to you quickly. You can filter out `-1` with `r = r[r>=0]; c = c[c>=0]`

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`DataFrame.melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html) with [`DataFrame.merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html), advantage is this solution working well if no match:

```
df11 = (df2.melt('ID_number', value_name='NewCol', var_name='value')
           .drop_duplicates(['ID_number','value'])
           .rename(columns={'ID_number':'ID'}))
df = df.merge(df11, on=['ID','value'], how='left')
print (df)
   ID to ignore value  NewCol
0   6       foo     A    0.88
1   2  whatever     B    0.22
2   4       idk     A    0.84
```

Answer (score 1):

Create map of key values from df2. Apply it on df

```
mapper = df2.set_index('ID_number').to_dict('index')
df['NewCol'] = df.apply(lambda x: mapper[x['ID']][x['value']], axis = 1)


    ID  to ignore   value   NewCol
0   6   foo         A       0.88
1   2   whatever    B       0.22
2   4   idk         A       0.84
```

A slightly different logic would be,

```
mapper = df2.set_index('ID_number').stack().to_dict()
df['NewCol'] = df[['ID', 'value']].apply(tuple, 1).map(mapper)
```

Comment: There isnt more efiicient way wothout using apply?

Answer (score 1):

Create `MultiIndex` for both dataframes and then use [`Index.map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.map.html):

```
In [4170]: x = df2.set_index('ID_number').stack()
In [4173]: y = df.set_index(['ID', 'value'])

In [4201]: y['NewCol'] = y.index.to_series().map(x.to_dict())

In [4207]: y.reset_index(inplace=True)

In [4208]: y
Out[4208]: 
   ID value to ignore  NewCol
0   6     A       foo    0.88
1   2     B  whatever    0.22
2   4     A       idk    0.84
```